# jquery mobile: how to create dynamic content only once, at page startup?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Here's what I want to do:

- load basket using Ajax
- show "wait" message
- once loaded, refresh basket.

When I try to use `pageinit` function:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
}
```

Console log show it's called 29 times!

Everything is on one HTML page, and I'm using `$.mobile.changePage()` to change pages. So I tried this hack:

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforeshow', function(evt, pg) {
    if (pg.prevPage.length==0) {
        /* first page = code executed once */
        var pg = $('#page-basket'),
            footer = pg.children( ":jqmData(role=footer)" );
        footer.hide().trigger('updatelayout');
        AjaxGetBasket( function(data) { console.log('ajax basket ok'); });
    }
});
```

But the layout is never updated.

How shall I do to modify page but only *once* at the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delegating the `pageinit` event handler so it only runs when `#page-basket` is initialized:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page-basket", function() {
    $(this).children(":jqmData(role=footer)").hide().trigger("updatelayout");
    AjaxGetBasket(function(data) {
        console.log("ajax basket ok");
    });
});
```

Comment: Erf... well it doesn't work: it's called only when the page is shown.

Comment: @Olivier, yup, that's what it's supposed to do. Maybe I misunderstood your question, when do you want the handler to be called?

Comment: I wanted to update the basket before each "`pagebeforechange`". And I wanted to "initialize" the basket with a message saying "downloading basket" or with the actual basket. But "`pagebeforechange`" is called *before* "`pageinit`" (which is not logical from my POV). So I have to do an ugly trick: in the "`pageinit`" I set a global variable saying "`initDone`" and from there I can update stuff and in "`pagebeforechange`", if "`initDone`" is false I do nothing, whereas if it's true, I do what I did in "`pageinit`" but now it works flawlessly. What I dont like is the duplication of code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand if your problem is solved, but i am in the same situation explained in the question and i have solved the problem binding a function to pagecreate event:

```
$(document).bind("pagecreate", function(e){
   // call ajax and update the DOM of first 'page'
});
```

and that's all.